# Moving data from Form to Form Silverlight WP7 Expression blend - SketchFlow

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I've tried this for one whole day and kinda gave up researching 
What i basically need to do is to update the info on the first page after selecting this button on form2

What i did was this :

```
private void btnContinue_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: Add event handler implementation here.

            Screen_1 S1 = new Screen_1();
            S1.CO2.Text = "TEXT";
            S1.CO3.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            //NavigationService.Source=new Uri("/Screen_1.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
            //NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Screen_1.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

        }
```

For some reason its not updating and navigation on expression blend doesnt work if i have code behind the button :(

Update:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Ink;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Expression.Prototyping.WindowsPhone.Mockups;
using System.Windows.Navigation;

namespace Analyser2_v1Screens
{
    public partial class Select : WindowsPhoneChrome
    {
        Screen_1 formOne = null;

        public Select()
        {
            // Required to initialize variables
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        public Select(Screen_1 formOneInstance)
        {
            // Required to initialize variables
            InitializeComponent();
            formOne = formOneInstance;

        }


        private void clickedC(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: Add event handler implementation here.
            //Screen_1 S1 = new Screen_1();
            //  S1.CO2.Content = "This is string content of a Button";
            //  S1.CO3.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            //  S1.test1.Text = "Tet";
            //NavigationService.Source=new Uri("/Screen_1.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
            //NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Screen_1.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

            formOne.test1.Text ="test";


        }


    }
}
```

STill not perfect enough

Answer (score 1):

Please share a snippet of your code. From I understand from your question, you can pass form 1's instance to form 2's constructor and alter elements of form1 from there.

```
// form 1 var
FormOne formOne = null;

// form 2's constructor
public FormTwo(FormOne formOneInstance)
{
   /*initialization etc*/
   formOne = formOneInstance;
}

// some method to alter an element in form 1
private void AlterSomthingInFormOne()
{
   formOne.SomeString = "Whatever value you'll need";
}
```

Comment: Hmm didnt really catch it sorry.

Comment: on your code, you're actually making a new Screen_1 object different from your target Screen_1 object. What you actually want is to pass the existing Screen_1 as parameter to Screen_2's constructor to allow Screen_2 to manipulate the elements/properties of Screen_1

Comment: Hmm i'm stuck at public FormTwo(FormOne formOneInstance)
{
   /*initialization etc*/
   formOne = formOneInstance;
}

Comment: it's probably because you're still using the Select() constructor instead of the new one. Where is your code that creates an instance of Select? adding a constructor isn't enough if you're not passing the instance of the existing Screen_1

Comment: Possible if i use static class?

Comment: Are you sure you're passing the Screen_1 to select correctly? check the code where you declared/created Select. if you delete the first constructor and build it again you should see where Select is being created.